# Two queries in same fetch_assoc, how to?

Tags: php, mysql

**How do I make a double query where I query the data of two columns found in the first query?**

I need to query TABLE teamstats on both csgo.team1 and csgo.team2

Here is a screenshot of the current output. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8DE1.jpg

I have tried using INNER JOIN like this, but this just joins the team1.

```php
$sql = "SELECT csgo.time, csgo.date, csgo.logo1, csgo.logo2, csgo.team1,
csgo.team2, csgo.event, teamstats.windrawwin,teamstats.mapsplayed,
teamstats.totalkills,teamstats.totaldeaths, teamstats.kdratio 
FROM csgo INNER JOIN teamstats ON csgo.team1=teamstats.tname 
ORDER BY csgo.date, csgo.time";
```

**TABLES**

```py
TABLE csgo >
#   Name    Datatype
1   date    date    
2   time    time    
3   team1   varchar(50) 
4   team2   varchar(50) 
5   event   varchar(50) 
6   logo1   text    
7   logo2   text    
8   id1     text    
9   id2     text    
10  style   text    
11  gameID PrimaryKey AI

TABLE teamstats >
#   Name        Datatype
1   tname       PrimaryKey varchar(50)  
2   windrawwin  text    
3   mapsplayed  varchar(8)  
4   totalkills  varchar(15) 
5   totaldeaths varchar(15) 
6   totalrounds varchar(15) 
7   kdratio     varchar(10)
```

**Full query**

```php
$sql = "SELECT csgo.time, csgo.date, csgo.logo1, csgo.logo2, csgo.team1, csgo.team2, csgo.event, teamstats.windrawwin, teamstats.mapsplayed, teamstats.totalkills,teamstats.totaldeaths, teamstats.kdratio FROM csgo INNER JOIN teamstats ON csgo.team1=teamstats.tname ORDER BY csgo.date, csgo.time";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='left'><table class='table table-striped table-dark'><tr><th>upcomming matches</th><th></th><th>W/D/L</th><th>MP</th><th>TK</th><th>TD</th><th>KD%</th></tr>";
    while($sup = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$sup["time"]." - ".$sup["date"]."</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='".$sup["logo1"]."'>".$sup["team1"]."</td>";
        #####team1 stats#############
        echo "<td>".$sup["windrawwin"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["mapsplayed"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["totalkills"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["totaldeaths"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["kdratio"]."</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["event"]."</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='".$sup["logo2"]."'>".$sup["team2"]."</td>";
        #####team2 stats#############
        echo "<td>".$sup["windrawwin"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["mapsplayed"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["totalkills"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["totaldeaths"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$sup["kdratio"]."</td>";
    }

    echo "</table></div><div class='right'>";} 
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

Can this be done with LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN?

Best regards

Comment: _“but this just joins the team1”_ - it joins based on what you tell it to. If you want it to join based on team2 as well - well then _add_ that to the ON clause.

Comment: I have tried this .. but it gives me errors. "INNER JOIN teamstats ON csgo.team1=teamstats.tname, csgo.team2=teamstats.tname ORDER BY csgo.date, csgo.time";

Comment: That’s not a place to use a comma; syntactically the ON clause is pretty much the same as a WHERE clause in that regard … This needs an AND or OR between the two partial conditions. (Here likely an OR, unless you are looking for records that have the same team name in both columns.)

Comment: this just queries team2 in both rows.. how do I use .$sup["windrawwin"]. for both team1 and team2?